# Spring- WS request input is coming null

Tags: java, spring, soap, jaxb, spring-ws

I am using Spring WS for producing a SOAP webservice. My Input request is coming null and pls help me in fixing the issue, as been struck for hours trying to figure out the issue..
Below is the snap of my code

wsdl: (sub set)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><wsdl:definitions 
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" jaxb:version="2.0" 
    targetNamespace="http://v4_0.webservice.commonuser.u90.org.com" xmlns:impl="http://v4_0.webservice.commonuser.u90.org.com" xmlns:intf="http://v4_0.webservice.commonuser.u90.org.com" xmlns:tns3="http://beans.v4_0.webservice.commonuser.u90.org.com" xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
     <wsdl:types>
      <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://beans.v4_0.webservice.gsec.commonuser.u90.org.com">
<complexType name="User">
    <sequence>
     <element name="userId" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
     <element name="userType" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
     <element name="firstName" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
    </sequence>
   </complexType>
      <complexType name="GetPersonByUserIdIP">
        <complexContent>
         <extension base="tns3:AttributeRequest">
          <sequence>
           <element name="userId" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
           <element name="userType" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
          </sequence>
         </extension>
        </complexContent>
       </complexType>
       <complexType name="GetPersonByUserIdOP">
          <sequence>
           <element name="user" nillable="true" type="tns3:User"/>
          </sequence>
       </complexType>

       <element name="getPersonByUserId">
        <complexType>
         <sequence>
          <element name="getPersonByUserIdIP" nillable="true" type="tns3:GetPersonByUserIdIP"/>
         </sequence>
        </complexType>
       </element>
       <element name="getPersonByUserIdResponse">
        <complexType>
         <sequence>
          <element name="getPersonByUserIdReturn" nillable="true" type="tns3:GetPersonByUserIdOP"/>
         </sequence>
        </complexType>
       </element>

       <wsdl:message name="getPersonByUserIdRequest">
          <wsdl:part element="impl:getPersonByUserId" name="parameters"/>
       </wsdl:message>
       <wsdl:message name="getOrganizationByUserIdRequest">
          <wsdl:part element="impl:getOrganizationByUserId" name="parameters"/>
       </wsdl:message>
       <wsdl:message name="getPersonListResponse">
          <wsdl:part element="impl:getPersonListResponse" name="parameters"/>
       </wsdl:message>
       <wsdl:message name="getPersonByUserIdResponse">
          <wsdl:part element="impl:getPersonByUserIdResponse" name="parameters"/
       </wsdl:message>
        <wsdl:operation name="getPersonByUserId">
             <wsdl:input message="impl:getPersonByUserIdRequest" name="getPersonByUserIdRequest"/>
             <wsdl:output message="impl:getPersonByUserIdResponse" name="getPersonByUserIdResponse"/>
          </wsdl:operation>
```

GetPersonByUserId

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import com.org.u90.unifieduser.webservice.v4_0.beans.GetPersonByUserIdIP;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "getPersonByUserIdIP"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "getPersonByUserId")
public class GetPersonByUserId
    implements Serializable
{

    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
    protected GetPersonByUserIdIP getPersonByUserIdIP;

    public GetPersonByUserIdIP getGetPersonByUserIdIP() {
        return getPersonByUserIdIP;
    }

    public void setGetPersonByUserIdIP(GetPersonByUserIdIP value) {
        this.getPersonByUserIdIP = value;
    }

}
```

GetPersonByUseridIP:

```
    import java.io.Serializable;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


  @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "GetPersonByUserIdIP", propOrder = {
    "userId",
    "userType"
})
public class GetPersonByUserIdIP
    extends AttributeRequest
    implements Serializable
{

    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
    protected String userId;
    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
    protected String userType;


    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String value) {
        this.userId = value;
    }

    public String getUserType() {
        return userType;
    }

    public void setUserType(String value) {
        this.userType = value;
    }

}
```

Spring WS-Config: (have mvc and Ws together)

```
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        XmlWebApplicationContext rootContext = new XmlWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.setConfigLocation("classpath*:config/spring/applicationContext.xml");

        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        dispatcherContext.register(WebConfigurer.class);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet(
          "Component-dispatcherServlet", new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherContext));
        dispatcher.addMapping("/web/*");


            MessageDispatcherServlet messageDispatcherServlet  = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
            messageDispatcherServlet.setApplicationContext(rootContext);
            messageDispatcherServlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
            ServletRegistration.Dynamic dessageDispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("MessageDispatcherServlet",
                    messageDispatcherServlet);
            dessageDispatcher.addMapping("/WS/40/*");
     }
    }

@Bean(name="cus")
    public Wsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition() {
        SimpleWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new SimpleWsdl11Definition();
        wsdl11Definition.setWsdl(new ClassPathResource("/WEB-INF/wsdl/CommonUserWS.wsdl"));
        return wsdl11Definition;
    }
```

Service class:

```
@Endpoint
public class CommonUserWS {
private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://v4_0.webservice.commonuser.u90.org.com";

@PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "getPersonByUserId")
    @ResponsePayload
    public JAXBElement<GetPersonByUserIdOP> getPersonByUserId(@RequestPayload GetPersonByUserIdIP getPersonByUserIdIP)
            throws ContextException {
        final GetPersonByUserIdOP output = new GetPersonByUserIdOP();
        JAXBElement<GetPersonByUserIdOP> jaxbElement = null;
        try {
            String userType = getPersonByUserIdIP.getUserType();
            String userId = getPersonByUserIdIP.getUserId();

            // impl logic

            QName qname = new QName("getPersonByUserId");
            jaxbElement = new JAXBElement<GetPersonByUserIdOP>(qname, GetPersonByUserIdOP.class, output);
        } catch (ContextException e) {
            throw e;
        }
        return jaxbElement;
    }
}
```

from the above class for GetPersonByUserIdIP - requestpayload is coming null

Below is the sample request i am sending:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v4="http://v4_0.webservice.commonuser.u90.org.com" xmlns:bean="http://beans.v4_0.webservice.commonuser.u90.org.com">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <bean:getPersonByUserId>
         <bean:getPersonByUserIdIP>
            <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
            <bean:attribute>name</bean:attribute>
            <bean:attribute>address</bean:attribute>

<bean:userId>hx52301</bean:userId>
            <bean:userType/>
         </bean:getPersonByUserIdIP>
      </bean:getPersonByUserId>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

i am getting below error:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <soapenv:Fault>
            <faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode>
            <faultstring>UserId is null.</faultstring>
        </soapenv:Fault>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

thanks for looking and any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your @RequestPayload, body should start with getPersonByUserIdIP instead of getPersonByUserId ?

```
 <soapenv:Body>
     <bean:getPersonByUserIdIP>
        <bean:attribute>name</bean:attribute>
        <bean:attribute>address</bean:attribute>

     <bean:userId>hx52301</bean:userId>
        <bean:userType/>
     </bean:getPersonByUserIdIP>
 </soapenv:Body>`
```

Comment: Hi Jayesh, If i remove the getPersonByUserId, its not working, as the request was not able to match with the endpoint.. i see the request coming with data in the server, but I see while jax-b unmarshalling, its failing and returning null

Comment: Can you post the class GetPersonByUseridIP?

Comment: already attached in the post.. tried to attach in the comments, by its not allowing due to length constraints.. pls find in the post with GetPersonByUseridIP :